# Whats the difference iterating over the queryset in these two ways?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was using Django for building my project and came across these two ways.

One way is :

```
users = Users.objects.filter(is_verified=True)

for user in users:
    print user.user.id
```

And the second way is :

```
users = Users.objects.filter(is_verified=True)

for user in users:
    print user.id
```

At first I thought the first way wont work but it was working and was quite slow then the second way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is looking at the `user` property inside of the individual `Users` object.

Basically the first one is doing:

`print users[x].user.id`

The second is doing:

`print users[x].id`

where `x` is the current index in the `for` loop.

If there is a user property inside of the `Users` object, the first is correct. Otherwise you'd want to just access the `id` property of the individual `Users` object.

An example of the `Users` class for the first scenario would be:

```
class Users(object):
  user = User()
```

An example of the `Users` class for the second senario would be:

```
class Users(object):
  id = 0
```

I think what's likely happening is that when accessing the `user` property on the `Users` object, it may be querying the database again. If you can include the `Users` class definition it would be easier to understand the root problem.

Answer (score 1):

First access user 's user' s id

Your `User` table has `user` field in it and you are accessing a_user.user.id

Second one access `User` table's `id` field